# accessing an objects key in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects

```
 const relationData = [
      {
        kids: [
          { text: 'Newborn', value: 'newborn' },
          { text: 'For under 5\'s', value: 'under5' },
          { text: 'Teenagers', value: 'teenagers' }
        ]
      },
```

how would i access the word `kids` in here? i want to check if myvalue `==` kids?

i have tried doing:

```
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

but this just seems to return me an index

PS I DONT WANT TO MENTION THE WORD `KIDS` AS I WONT IT TO BE RESUABLE

Comment: Do you want to have an array of data or a key value (dictionary) pair of data?

Comment: Look for use of `Object.keys()`.  This will return you the keys for an object (funnily enough!).  So loop over your array, check the keys of each object in the array.

Comment: yes key would just be the current index, you can use your loop to print out each obj like `for (var key in data) { console.log(data[key]); } ` or access kids array like `console.log(data[key].kids);`

Comment: @AndrewLohr i dont want to specify kids though coz it could change (sorry should have made that clear)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. 
You want to get the value of the properties of the objects inside your array ?

Comment: @Ellone no i just want to get the name of the array which is kids. but i want to be able to say `if myValue == 'kids'` but i dont want to hardcode kids. i want to access it like array[0] etc but im not sure how to do it for objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the keys of each obj in relationData like below

```
for (var index in relationData) {
  var keys = Object.keys(relationData[index]);
  console.log(keys.indexOf("kids") > -1)// then relationData has an object with a key of "kids"
}
```

"kids" can be a variable as well so you can reuse this with other key names

Answer (score 0):

```
if('kids' in relationData[0]) {
//if key exists, do this
}
else {
//if key does not exist, do this
}
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate over the array and access the value of each kids you should do:

```
for (let x = 0; x < relationalData.length; x++){
  for (let y = 0; y < relationalData[x].kids.length; y++) { 
    console.log(relationalData[x].kids[y].value
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that according to your data structure you have two arrays:

1. relationalData
2. for each relational data object you have an array of kids: relationalData[X].kids

If you want to access the keys of each of the objects inside relationalData you should do

```
Object.keys(relationalData[x])
```